# Python in browser with NLTK or alternative?

Tags: python, nltk, transcrypt, skulpt

Is there a Python front-end that supports nltk?

I am building a custom application that needs to do stemming and stopping, and related processing, on a simple words query from inside the browser.  I am familiar with nltk's stem/stop functionality, but a quick google of Python front-end alternatives [listed in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30155551/8542716) does not turn up support for nltk.  I tried pypy.js [from its website](http://pypyjs.org), entered "import nltk," and it failed.

(I plan to use CherryPy as the back-end, if it matters, to serve up the application to the browser on first contact, and process the outputs.)

Is there a front-end that works with nltk?  Alternatively:

- Can I add nltk support to any of these environments, and how?
- Is there another library that does stemming/stopping that works with these front-ends?

Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it multi-lingual or for a particular language. If it's just for one language and it's analytic with no inflection, even if agglutinative (such as Khmer), considering it's for the browser, you may find a lighter approach that doesn't require full nltk, such as dict based longest word approach (step up from max match). Works well for chinese also. For speed improvement, might use bigram to look at only a subset of the dictionary.

Comment: I really only need to "stem" the words (running, runs, ran --> run), and prune "stop" words (the, a, an, if, was, ...), and I don't need to be so picky about it; I'm building a research prototype.  I could probably just ingest some code, but also I understand there are Javascript libraries that can do this.  Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best off using a JavaScript NLP library of which there are several, like NLPJS, although I can't judge its quality.

If you use Transcrypt in your browser you can use objects and call functions from that library without conversion.
So you can program in Python, while your library is in JS.

Comment: Interesting!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use flask to show your python in web browser. Flask is a web framework. This means flask provides you with tools, libraries and technologies that allow you to build a web application.
In your case you can use flask to get data from browser and analyse your data and then show the result in browser.
you can see a word cloud example with flask [here](https://github.com/michael-pacheco/flask-d3-wordcloud).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems that Flask is a templating engine, and all the Python runs on the server side.  I see no way for a client to run Python; at most, it could run JavaScript that is returned as part of the template, but then I have to write that script, and I'm back to my original question.